# How to change wrong activated old gem file version to new version

Tags: rubygems, version, mismatch, passenger-apache

Bundler version 2.4.20

Rails 6.1.7.6

Debian 11, apache

ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]

starting redmine by browser it throws this error:

```
App 121717 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: You have already activated strscan 1.0.3, but your Gemfile requires strscan 3.0.7. Since strscan is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports strscan as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)
```

`

gem list -d strscan shows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

strscan (3.0.7, 3.0.0)
    Authors: Minero Aoki, Sutou Kouhei, Charles Oliver Nutter
    Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/strscan
    Licenses: Ruby, BSD-2-Clause
    Installed at (3.0.7): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
                 (3.0.0, default): /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0

    Provides lexical scanning operations on a String.
```

`

No plan what to do ..

expecting new gem file version as activated